# Angular 2 http call url based on another service

Tags: angular

So I have a component that sets `selectedCountry` in a service. And I have another service that gets data from `api/${selectedCountry}`, and I want the service to subscribe when the change of country has been made, thus change of data will be reflected. Is there a way to do that?

Here's what I have currently:

```
private url: string;
private headers: Headers;
private options: RequestOptions;

constructor(private http: Http,
    private settingService: SettingService) {
    this.url = `/api/${this.settingService.selectedCountry}`;
    this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
}

getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);  
}
```

Please let me know how to do this, or if I am just overthinking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to subscribe to the first service ( `SettingService` ) from the second one (whose code snippet you have pasted I assume) and watch for changes to the `selectedCountry` property there and then once there is a change run code.

## SettingService

```
...
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'
...

export class SettingService{
    ...
    // Observable string sources
    private selectedCountrySource = new Subject<string>()

    // Observable string streams
    selectedCountryChange$ = this.selectedCountrySource.asObservable()
    ...

    //Wherever you are changing the selected country add the next line
    this.selectedCountrySource.next(selectedCountry)

   //What this does is emit that there is a change. The selectedCountry    
   //parameter will be the new country
}
```

## OtherService

```
private url: string;
private headers: Headers;
private options: RequestOptions;

constructor(private http: Http, private settingService: SettingService) {
    this.url = `/api/${this.settingService.selectedCountry}`;
    this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

    //Subscribe to the SettingService for changes
    sessionService.selectedCountryChange$.subscribe(
        newSelectedCountry => {
           this.url =`/api/${newSelectedCountry}`;

           //Call getTasks if needed to update
           this.getTasks() 
    })
}

getTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);  
}
```

Comment: Make the `SettingService` an Injectable and define `selectedCountry` as a field perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But `${this.settingService.selectedCountry}` kept coming back as null :/